# Value in console.log is different than in DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have following component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isEnabled: 'yes',
    };
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.isEnabled);

    return (
      <div className="rd-pills rd-pills--fullwidth">
        {this.state.isEnabled}
        <input
          id="referral-disabled"
          className="rd-pills__input"
          onClick={() => this.setState({ isEnabled: 'no' })}
        />
        <label
          htmlFor="referral-disabled"
          className="rd-pills__pill rd-pills__pill--half"
        >
          Disable
        </label>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ isEnabled: 'no' })}>
          Disable
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

If I click **button** `console.log(this.state.isEnabled);` returns `no` and `{this.state.isEnabled}` is evaluated to `no`.

If I click **input** `console.log(this.state.isEnabled);` returns `no` and `{this.state.isEnabled}` is evaluated to **`yes`**. (initial state)

In second case `debugger;` also says that `this.state.isEnabled` is `no`.

How is this possible? Why in the same render cycle value in DOM and state variable are different?

Comment: use `true` and `false`.

Comment: I've tried that. It does not solve my problem. In this example I used strings just to show difference in DOM.

Comment: http://www.webpackbin.com/N1ep9vVUf it actually allways returns 'no', besides first render

Comment: not getting the issue that u described, see the `jsfiddle` its working properly : https://jsfiddle.net/qsy0azmL/